DataTable is initialized with a "No result to display" but the dt-length, dt-search, dt-info and dt-paging is showing and dt-paging NaN as data-dt-idx
jQuery: 3.7.1
DataTable: 2.0.6
$(#dtTable).DataTable({
    paging: true,
    ordering: true,
    serverSide: true,
    searching: true,
    // ordering of the table default [column,direction]
    order: [[0, "desc"]],
    ajax: {
       url: "/ajax_url",
       type: "POST"
    },
    pagingType: 'simple_numbers',
    responsive: true,
    processing: true,
    lengthMenu: [
        [5, 10, 25, 50],
        [5, 10, 25, 50],
    ],
    pageLength: 10,
    bSort: true,
    searchDelay: 1500,
    columnDefs: [
        { responsivePriority: 1, targets: 0 },
        { responsivePriority: 2, targets: -1 },
    ]
})

response: {"draw":1,"data":[]}
I was expecting just a displayed table with no filters and pagination as table has no result to display.

Please create  a minimal reproducible example

You should include recordsTotal and recordsFiltered in your response. Records filtered will be 0 since your result set is empty, as you show: "data": []. Also, make sure your draw value matches the value sent in the request.

"I was expecting just a displayed table with no filters and pagination as table has no result to display." Maybe this is a misunderstanding about how DataTables works, but you always get these elements displayed, even when the table is empty (unless you explicitly do something to alter the default behavior). You can see for yourself by running one of the relevant official examples.

@andrewJames its due to the missing recordsTotal and recordsFiltered

It seems as though you're using server-side data. What happens if you remove the draw from your result set? According to the documentation, you are perhaps missing some values from your result data: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Example-data — particularly recordsTotal and recordsFiltered.
This is the example from the documentation:
{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [
        {
            "DT_RowId": "row_3",
            "DT_RowData": {
                "pkey": 3
            },
            "first_name": "Angelica",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "office": "London",
            "start_date": "9th Oct 09",
            "salary": "$2,875"
        },
        {
            "DT_RowId": "row_17",
            "DT_RowData": {
                "pkey": 17
            },
            "first_name": "Ashton",
            "last_name": "Cox",
            "position": "Technical Author",
            "office": "San Francisco",
            "start_date": "12th Jan 09",
            "salary": "$4,800"
        },
        ...
    ]
}

